# How do I show a youtube video on full screen when a link is clicked?

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

In one of my web app I am showing a youtube videos thumb nails like

```
<img height="150px" id="youtubeImage" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/default.jpg" href="">
```

I am fetching the video id from database. I want to show a full screen if this video while clicking on this link. I showed this in a iframe using jQuery. But how to show this in full screen ?

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a jQuery answer, but this can almost be achieved by using the URL:

> http://www.youtube.com/v/[VIDEO_ID]

This will redirect to

> http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/[VIDEO_ID]

Which has the video taking up the full browser tab. Not strictly fullscreen as it won't hide the player components but I'm not sure you can do it any other way.

Comment: thanks for the reply and .. I need to show the full screen video in the same page itself ...