# Play youtube video in fullscreen?

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

I am doing a button click using jquery,

When button clicked it should play a youtube video in full screen.

How this can be achieved.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when I know, you can not, only change the URL address of the video. The experience of this.
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11026942/2837634)